# det equation over the integers

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A\in {M_2 (Z)} $ . If $\det (A^3+I)=1$ -find $A$. I tried using eigenvalues and the fact that if they are not rational (or if they are not real) - they must be conjugated but the calculation is just to big

Comment: Any $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with $A^3 = 0$, of which there are many, clearly satisfies the given equation. Is there any other infromation given?

Comment: Sorry.i editez. n=2. @anomaly : unfortunately, Î feel that this is not the only solution

Comment: To explicitly talk about the eigenvalues: an integer matrix $A$ is a solution if and only if its eigenvalues satisfy $(\lambda_1^3 + 1)(\lambda_2^3 + 1)  = 1$.

Comment: @DanLeonte: Oh, it's definitely not.

Comment: @anomaly The OP has edited the question such that $n=2$. In this case, the solutions are exactly those nilpotent matrices.

Comment: @user1551: Ah, thanks, that wasn't there when I originally answered the question.

Comment: @user1551- how do you know nilpotent matrices are the only solution? Maybe șome complex pair of eigenvalues also satisfies the equation